# Find differential equation of ellipse

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

How can I find the differantial equation of one parametered ellipse family with the equation :
$$t^{2}/c + y^{2} = 1/(c-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Using implicit differentiation with respect to $t$ we have:

$$\frac{2t}{c}+2\cdot y\cdot y'=0 \Leftrightarrow t+c\cdot y\cdot y'=0$$